# as...as + past participle

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, as

> 1- This case may not be quite ***as urgent as*** ***once thought***.

Which one of the following sentences is the full version of the sentence above?

> 2- This case may not be quite ***as urgent as it was once thought***.
>
> 3- This case may not be quite ***as urgent as once we thought***.

Comment: #2 is invalid, because ***once*** implies ***in the past***, which conflicts with Present Tense *as **is** thought*. #1 and #3 are valid, as are #4: ***...as urgent as was once thought*** and #5: ***...as urgent as we once thought.*** Plus there are 4 more "valid" permutations with ***once*** at the end of the utterance (*after* the verb ***thought*** rather than before it). They're all equivalent, and you can take your pick, but I would just say #3 (with ***once*** moved before "subject" ***we***) strikes me as a rather "poetic" stylistic inversion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, while you were commenting, I was editing the question, including the tenses, word order and the numbers of the sentences...

Comment: @Jan: Hmm. It was only a comment to accompany my closevote anyway (it's POB, imho), but it's even less meaningful now there are only 2 numbered examples in the question rather than the 3 I originally addressed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, OK; I reverted my edit.

Comment: @Jan: Over the years I've been on ELL (and ELU), I've become persuaded that usually we should *not* edit question text to remove "errors". The idea being that other users here can get a better understanding of what the OP does and doesn't know by seeing their text "in the raw", so to speak, which may help us construct more finely-targeted answers.

Comment: I have edited the sentence 2. Is it an acceptable version right now?

Comment: Yes, it is. And in the sentence 2, it sounds better if you say "we once" instead of "once we."

Comment: Unless the original sentence is actually known for a fact (through edits or an author's testimony), any number of versions *could* be the long version. There is no single version that it must always be.